# How To Change The PointBackgroundColor Dynamically In ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js, linechart

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Testing Chart.js Line Chart</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-sW/w8s4RWTdFFSduOTGtk4isV1+190E/GghVffMA9XczdJ2MDzSzLEubKAs5h0wzgSJOQTRYyaz73L3d6RtJSg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="add()" id="btnAdd">Add 10</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="subtract()" id="btnSubtract">Subtract 10</button>
    <canvas id="chart_canvas">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Set Chart Global Variables
    let x_values = [];
    let y_values = [];
    let new_number = 0;
    let index = 0;
    let chart_canvas = document.getElementById("chart_canvas");

    // Intialize Data
    x_values.push(index);
    y_values.push(index);

    // Create New Chart
    my_chart = new Chart(chart_canvas, {
        type: "line",
        data: {
            labels: [x_values[index]],
            datasets: [{
                backgroundColor: "#d8dee980",
                pointBackgroundColor: "#81a1c1ff",
                fill: true,
                pointStyle: "circle",
                label: "Values",
                data: [y_values[index]]
            }]
        }
    });

    // ------ Local Functions ------

    function add() {
        index = my_chart.data.datasets.length;
        new_number += 10;
        my_chart.data.labels.push(index);
        my_chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
            dataset.data.push(new_number);
        });

        // -------
        //The below line is changing all point background colors instead of the last one only!
        my_chart.data.datasets[index - 1].pointBackgroundColor = "#88c0d0ff";
        // -------

        my_chart.update();

    }

    function subtract() {
        index = my_chart.data.datasets.length;
        new_number -= 10;
        my_chart.data.labels.push(index);
        my_chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
            dataset.data.push(new_number);
        });

        // -------
        //The below line is changing all point background colors instead of the last one only!
        my_chart.data.datasets[index - 1].pointBackgroundColor = "#bf616aff";
        // -------

        my_chart.update();
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Expected Output / Objective:**

- When the "**Add 10**" button is clicked, a new point entry needs to be added with a `pointBackgroundColor` in green.
- When the "**subtract 10**" button is clicked, a new point entry needs to be added with a `PointBackgroundColor` in red.

**Current Outcome:**

All point background colors are changing together instead of the last one only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be an array if you want different colors for different points in the line.

```
pointBackgroundColor:["#88c0d0ff"]
```

when you add a new dot then push the desired color in the above array.

```
my_chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
            dataset.data.push(new_number);
            //New dot is pushed with desired color.
            dataset.pointBackgroundColor.push("#88c0d0ff");
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Testing Chart.js Line Chart</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-sW/w8s4RWTdFFSduOTGtk4isV1+190E/GghVffMA9XczdJ2MDzSzLEubKAs5h0wzgSJOQTRYyaz73L3d6RtJSg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="add()" id="btnAdd">Add 10</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="subtract()" id="btnSubtract">Subtract 10</button>
    <canvas id="chart_canvas">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Set Chart Global Variables
    let x_values = [];
    let y_values = [];
    let new_number = 0;
    let index = 0;
    let chart_canvas = document.getElementById("chart_canvas");
    

    // Intialize Data
    x_values.push(index);
    y_values.push(index);

    // Create New Chart
    my_chart = new Chart(chart_canvas, {
        type: "line",
        data: {
            labels: [x_values[index]],
            datasets: [{
                backgroundColor: "#d8dee980",
                pointBackgroundColor:["#88c0d0ff"],//Make it an array.
                fill: true,
                pointStyle: "circle",
                label: "Values",
                data: [y_values[index]]
            }]
        }
    });

    // ------ Local Functions ------

    function add() {
        index = my_chart.data.datasets.length;
        new_number += 10;
        my_chart.data.labels.push(index);
        
        my_chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
            dataset.data.push(new_number);
            //New dot is pushed with desired color.
            dataset.pointBackgroundColor.push("#88c0d0ff");
        });

        // -------
        //The below line is changing all point background colors instead of the last one only!
        //my_chart.data.datasets[index - 1].pointBackgroundColor = "#88c0d0ff";
        // -------

        my_chart.update();

    }

    function subtract() {
        index = my_chart.data.datasets.length;
        new_number -= 10;
        my_chart.data.labels.push(index);
        my_chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
            dataset.data.push(new_number);
            //New dot is pushed with desired color.
            dataset.pointBackgroundColor.push("#bf616aff");
        });

        // -------
        //The below line is changing all point background colors instead of the last one only!
        //my_chart.data.datasets[index - 1].pointBackgroundColor = "#bf616aff";
        // -------

        my_chart.update();
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please, as a side question, can this work for `backgroundColor` as well? I have tried it with `backgroundColor` but it wasn't changing. Maybe, we can't make the backgroundColor an array like the `pointBackgroundColor`, or am I missing something else? Thank you very much!

Comment: Background cannot be array its same throughout.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you for pointing that out. Please how can we change the `backgroundColor` or the fill color then?

Comment: Can you explain your use case first? What do you want?

Comment: I posted a new question for clarity purposes. You can check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73024618/how-to-change-charts-backgroundcolor-for-specific-dataset-with-onclick-event-us